# Separate test execution with Maven

Tags: java, maven, testing

Is it possible to configure Maven so that it executes all test classes separately as I would execute them from command line:

```
mvn -Dtest=Test1 test && mvn -Dtest=Test2 test && mvn -Dtest=Test3 test
```

I thought it could be achievable with maven surefire plugin. With configuration like:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test1</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/Test1.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test2</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/Test2.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test3</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/Test3.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: Why want you do that?

Comment: @Jens There is a test class that fails when executed during standard build. However it runs successfully when executed separately and it doesn't affect the test quality.

Comment: If it fails during the standard build, it should be repaired or eliminated.

Answer (score 2):

The option

```
        <configuration>
            <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
        </configuration>
```

solved the problem as it forced each test to run on a separate VM

Comment: If that's the solution your tests keeping static states etc... you should check the test in depth...

Comment: @khmarbaise It all started with a `@SpyBean` that did its job fine when the corresponding test class ran separately. But when the test ran together with other tests (via `mvn package` or `mvn test`) the `@SpyBean` stopped to intercept method calls. Maybe I'll ask another question related to this problem, but I wanted to fix it as soon as possible. Besides all the tests should normally be executed separately without any problems. If they don't - something is wrong with test design.

Comment: @khmarbaise I've created another question related to the problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68620654/spybean-doesnt-intercept-method-calls-when-test-class-isnt-executed-separatel